# How to replace last substring of a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the last substring of a string without splitting the whole string. Exp: "I am a newbie" to "I am a student". But this piece of code not working. Please, help!

```
var old = "newbie"
var new_ = "student"
var str = str.replace(new RegExp(old + '$'), new_);
```

Comment: Its working. What error do you get?

Comment: [That code works fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/n7c6uoej/)

Comment: Maybe your `str` has spaces at the end? Try using `str = str.trim();` first.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks!! You solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working. But you had not declared the `str` variable with the value `"I am a newbie"`. You directly tried to replace, which may have caused it to not work.

```js
var old = "newbie"
var new_ = "student"
var str = "I am a newbie"


str = str.replace(new RegExp(old + '$'), new_);

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general answer, if you want to replace the last word of the input string by another value, but you do not know what that word will be beforehand, you can use a regular expression.

```js
string.replace(/\w+$/, 'student');
```

```js
const strings = [
  'I am a newbie',
  'I like sunshine', 
  'I do not like pheasants'
];
strings.forEach(e => {
  console.log(`Updated ${e} to ${e.replace(/\w+$/, 'student')}`);
});
```